# KML name column from a merged table

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I have a merged table here, merged on the "level" field:

https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1JJHwwJLW1CqrG3PZv3kMBrRJio-5f_28g_rJrYU#map:id=3

When I try to export this as KML, the markers end up labeled with the 
value from the "level" field, despite the existence of a column called 
"Name".

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column-name must be exactly `name` (not `Name` , it's case-sensitive)

Go to Edit>change columns.

Here you may either:

- change the name of the column to `name`
- or move the `Name`-column to the top(when no `name`-column exists, the first column will be used as name for the placemark, currently `level` is the first column)

Comment: For the record, renaming the column worked fine. This surprised me; many uses of FT column names seem to be case-insensitive. Thanks for your help!